# Не работает поиск контакта по номеру

Tags: java, android

Не могу понять, почему не работает поиск контакта по имени. Искал в интернете, но везде примерно одно и то же. Кто может подсказать, в чем проблема? Крашится при попытке достать display_name

```
String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID, ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.Contacts.STARRED, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTACT_STATUS, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTACT_PRESENCE };
String selection = "PHONE_NUMBERS_EQUAL(" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + ",?) AND " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { phoneNumber };
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);

for(int j = 0;j < cursor.getCount();j++) {
    sms.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("display_name")));
}
```

Comment: Если вы не напишите на какой конкретно строчке падает и с какой ошибкой, то помочь вам будет практически невозможно.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб cursor считается пустым при вызове getColumnIndexOrThrow. Но при вызове getColmnNames он выдаёт имена, следовательно пустым cursor быть не может

Comment: вроде положено `cursor.moveToFirst()` вызывать, перед получением данных, т.к. изначально курсор расположен перед первой строкой результата запроса.

Comment: @zRrr  ай, точно же. Спасибо большое. На андроиде недавно, пока ещё не со всеми особенностям знаком

Comment: @zRrr, вы б как ответ опубликовали б... Статы сайта повысим)

Comment: @zRrr Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*из комментария:*

Положено `cursor.moveToFirst()` вызывать перед получением данных, т.к. изначально курсор расположен перед первой строкой результата запроса.